# ReactiveCocoa: Immediately send the latest value when there's a new subscription

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I have a bunch of manual `RACSubject` properties in a particular view model; I am calling `sendNext` at certain points in the code, and I want new subscribers to these signals to immediately have their `subscribeNext` block be called with the latest value in that signal. Is this possible?

As an example, if I am sending the values `1 -> 12 -> 42` and then down the line there's a new subscriber, I want that subscriber to get `42` straight off (and then obviously listen for more pushes when they come about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so it looks like I wanted to be using the `RACSubject` subclass `RACReplaySubject` instead. Not sure how I missed that one!